# Pandas: Use Variables as Columns

Tags: function, python-3.x, pandas

I am attempting define a function that passes variables into various dataframe functions. In the case below, I'm using .loc with the defined variables. For some reason, I can't seem to produce the desired result after the function is applied.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1':['A','A','B','B'], 'COL2': [1,1,2,2,], 'COL3': [2,3,4,6]})
col2 = 'COL2'
def pandfun(df, col2):
    df = df.loc[df[col2] == 1]
df = pandfun(df, col2)
```

The desired result is:

```
    COL1    COL2    COL3
0     A       1       2
1     A       1       3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it looks like it's operating on a copy you should return `df.loc[df[col2]==1]` and then assign the returned df to `df`

Comment: So I tried taking out "df = " from the "df.loc..." line, but it returned nothing.

Comment: change your func to: `def pandfun(df, col2):
    return df.loc[df[col2] == 1]` and then it should work

Comment: That did it. You're the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is operating on a copy so you should return it so it assigns outside the function scope:

```
In [117]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1':['A','A','B','B'], 'COL2': [1,1,2,2,], 'COL3': [2,3,4,6]})
col2 = 'COL2'
def pandfun(df, col2):
    return df.loc[df[col2] == 1]
df = pandfun(df, col2)
df

Out[117]:
  COL1  COL2  COL3
0    A     1     2
1    A     1     3
```